# what are most frequently used real-time examples of Django custom middleware? It would be great if a code snippet is also shared

Tags: python, django, middleware, django-middleware

what are most frequently used real-time examples of Django custom middleware? 
It would be great if a code snippet is also shared.

Answer (score 9):

1. Handling Authentication/Authorization/Auditing using custom django middleware.

> ```
> class AuthenticationMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
>     def process_request(self, request):
>         header_token = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', None)
>         if header_token is not None:
>             header_token = header_token.split() 
>             if header_token[0] == "Basic":
>                 try:
>                     token = base64.b64decode(header_token[1]).decode(HTTP_HEADER_ENCODING).partition(':')[0]
>                     token_obj = Token.objects.get(key = token)
>                     request.user = token_obj.user
>                 except Token.DoesNotExist:
>                     pass
>         current_user = getattr(request, 'user', None)
>         _do_set_current_user(lambda: current_user)
>
>     def process_response(self, request, response):
>         clear_current_user()
>         return response
> ```

2. Metrics Instrumentation - To measure response time, throughput, transactions of your application

https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/python-django

3. Custom CSRF middleware to skip/check on specific requests

> ```
> from django.middleware.csrf import CsrfViewMiddleware
> import codecs
>
> class CustomCsrfMiddleware(CsrfViewMiddleware):
>     def process_view(self, request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs):
>         csrf_skip_header = request.META.get('HTTP_SKIP_CSRF_CHECK')
>         if csrf_skip_header # and add your logic here:
>                 return None
>         else:
>             return super(CustomCsrfMiddleware, self).process_view(request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

A fairly common piece of Middleware is forcing users to use Https. Here's a snippet:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponsePermanentRedirect


class SSLifyMiddleware(object):
    """Force all requests to use HTTPs. If we get an HTTP request, we'll just
    force a redirect to HTTPs."""

    def process_request(self, request):
        secure_url = url.replace('http://', 'https://')
        return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(secure_url)
```

Comment: It's better to handle HTTPs redirection in the network level than in an application using middleware